# Reset Google sheet after form submission

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, reset

Is there a way to use script to remove data from a Sheet a certain time after a form submission?
I am trying to use Sheets as a database with a form attached. Users choose the data they want using a Form. This then populates a Sheet with the request which then uses vlookups to choose the corresponding data from another tab on the Sheet. I am then using  AutoCrat to produce a Google Doc with this data for the user.
The problem I have is that for AutoCrat to work properly with the vlookups I need the sheet to reset itself after AutoCrat has run. Ideally the sheet would not need to be opened at all as AutoCrat triggers on Form submission. Is there a way to use script to remove data from a Sheet a certain time after a Form submission?

Comment: Yes you can write a script to delete data from a spreadsheet.

Comment: You would need to install your own "On Form Submit" trigger with an associated function name in a script project bound to your Sheet.  If you want to clear values, and not affect formatting then you'd need to avoid deleting rows.  According to the Stack Overflow rules, your question is "off-topic" because it's general.  In order to answer your question, it would be more like a tutorial.  If you wanted to know whether it's possible before you spend time and effort on it, then, "Yes, it's possible."

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `onFormSubmit` trigger.

#### Snippet

```
function createTrigger() {
   var form = FormApp.openById('FORM_ID');
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('deleteFunction')
       .forForm(form)
       .onFormSubmit()
       .create();
}
```

```
function deleteFunction() {
   Utilities.sleep("TIME_IN_MS");
   //delete unnecessary data
}
```

#### Explanation

The above code is composed of two functions:

- `createTrigger` which is the function that creates the `onFormSubmit` trigger and attaches it to the `deleteFunction` function;
- `deleteFunction` which is used to delete the data you want; in order to add a certain delay/time for deleting the data, the `Utilities.sleep()` has been added.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers);
- [Apps Script - onFormSubmit() Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onformsubmit);
- [Apps Script Utilities Class - sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds).